# Do I have to explicitly generate a migration for the foreign key in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, migration

Suppose I have Model Person and Model Book. One person has many books. I have a has_many books in Person's model and belongs_to in Book's model. When I generate those scaffold, there're no foreign keys in the database. Do I have to always create a migration using the convention, for example book_id, manually ? Why rails does not link thing on the database ? I didn't figure out how Rails knots everything together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or what is the same:

```
rails g scaffold book name:string person:references
```

this will create a person_id field in the book table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for rails to make any assumption about that. You may create foreign key with scaffold, or fix migration by yourself before run it.

```
rails generate scaffold book name:string person_id:integer
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enforce database foreign keys, you have to use a gem like [foreigner](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner)